# Orbot transparent proxy requires enabling manually

Tags: dns, tor, systemless-root, orbot

My phone is HTC One M8 on Marshmallow stock ROM, rooted with Magisk.

I've installed Orbot and noticed it doesn't work in transparent proxying mode when proxying all apps. It requires manual proxy settings in Wi-Fi or mobile network.

If I proxy only selected apps, it works.

I suspect it's due to DNS requests being blocked by iptables rules set by Orbot. They're trying to be sent directly, not respecting Orbot's proxy.

How can I verify it and possibly fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is due to ip tables enforced by Orbot (it tends to use IP tables bundled with the application and not default ip tables)

You can try the following workaround;

- Go to Settings menu, check **use default iptables** and uncheck (or leave unchecked) the option to allowed it for tethering i.e **Tor tethering**. If the tethering option is off and the use default iptables option is on, it should work.
- Make sure to enable **Request Root Access**, **Transparent Proxying** and **Tor Everything**.

> Tor's transparent proxy runs on port 9040 by default and forces apps
>   to proxy through it, so you can tell whether or not it is working by
>   using Orbot's restrictive hosts policy to allow/deny traffic and see
>   how the app behaves.

You also use Orbot's VPN service to bypass filters and firewalls and see if you do "transparent proxy" for all apps:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work at all with default iptables. Check.torproject.org says I'm not using Tor.

Comment: Ok the issue, is because the default ip tables that come with ROM need to be updated. You can find some tutorials on how tp update default ip tables binaries, it should work

Comment: I was suggesting you to update the iptables